# SQL Query to match if data is not present in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables named `tblStockManagement` and `tblFolding` in my database. i have column `Name` in `tblFolding` table and column `FoldingID` as Foreign Key in `tblStockManagement` table. now i have comboBox in my Winform and i want `Names` of Items in combobox from `tblFolding` Table but only those items that are not in `tblStockManagement` Table.

(because i dont want to select data again if it is already in `tblStockManagement` table . instead i will update the quantity later).

[image: tblFolding Table]

[image: tblStockManagement Table]

these are the screenshots of both of tables. please tell me how can i do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is you need.Basically a sub query which gets all folding id and using not in operator I exclude those matching sets.

```
SELECT Name
  FROM tblFolding 
  WHERE FoldingID NOT IN (
    SELECT FoldingID
    FROM tblStockManagement 
  )
;
```

Comment: Will not work as expected if the sub-query returns a NULL.

Answer (score 1):

`NOT EXISTS` version:

```
select *
from tblFolding f
where not exists (select * from tblStockManagement SM
                  where sm.FoldingID = f.FoldingID)
```

`NOT EXISTS` is "NULL safe", which `NOT IN` isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQL NOT](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/not.php) condition

```
Select Name
From tblFolding
Where FoldingId Not In (Select FoldingId From tblStockManagement)
Order By Name
```